# Best Kafka Producer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I noticed that there are several producers our there:

```
org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer<K,V>

kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer
```

What's the difference between them? Which one should be used and why?Please suggest!

Answer (score 2):

`kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer` is the old legacy producer which was used in Kafka 0.8.x This was implemented in Scala but has a dedicated Java API. It's still available in the common Kafka artifact.

`org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer` is the new producer implementation, written in Java, has a lot of improvements compared to the old and is the one you should use with Kafka 0.9.0.0 Version. This is available in a separate client dependency with coordinates:

`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0.0</version>
</dependency>`